# Telegram Web App, неправильный формат json, запрос отправляется успешно, как правильно оформить?

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot, telegram, api

```py
payload = {
            "chat_id": user_tg_id,
            "text": "Откройте ссылку",
            "reply_markup" : {
                "inline_keyboard" : [[{"text" : "Open Url", 
                                       "web_app": {"WebAppInfo":{"url": redirect_url}}}
                                      ]
                                     ]
                }
        }
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
        response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Следует отформатировать код и предоставить больше информации о полученной ошибке, если такая возникает.